# Triggering a sequence on Mainstage and on a Analog Rytm with a Beatstep controller

Tags: midi

I am trying to trigger (in sync...) a sequence on the playback software of Mainstage and another beat sequence on the Analog Rytm with a Beatstep controller (or any usb controller for that matter). First, is it possible and if so, how can I do so ?